# Can we see what code is inside a bootstrap class?

Tags: html, css, class, bootstrap-4, frontend

There are classes inside the button tag `<button class="btn btn-outline-primary">` and I want to see the code used in `btn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Bootstrap CSS and JS source files. For example, the non-minified links for Bootstrap 4 are:

- [Bootstrap Stylesheet](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css)
- [Bootstrap JS Bundle](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js)

Also, modern browsers with the Developer Tools extension allow you to inspect the live webpage. You can see the applied classes and events for every element.